# What's the R equivalent of progn in lisp?

Tags: r, lisp

In lisp there is syntax to execute several expressions in sequence within function arguments. Given R's lispy origins, I'm wondering is there an equivalent feature in R? I'm imagining writing something like the following:

```
with(heat,
     do(qqnorm(loss), qqline(loss)))
```

Comment: The various `apply` functions: `?sapply`, `?lapply`, `?apply`, etc. are probably what you want. If `heat` is a dataframe, then `lapply(heat, function(x) {qqnorm(loss); qqline(loss)})` will create the `qqnorm` plot (and add the `qqline`) for each column.

Comment: Maybe something like `lapply(c(qqnorm, qqline), function(f) f(loss))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R, brackets are used to group multiple statements in a "compound statement", which appears to be the role played by `progn` in Lisp. As with `progn`, all of the component statements are evaluated, but only the value of the final statement is returned.

```
with(mtcars, 
     {qqnorm(mpg); qqline(mpg)})
```